# How to copy page/post from one theme to another?

Tags: theme-development, themes, theme-customizer, theme-twenty-twenty-one

I was using default wordpress 2022 theme and created few post & page templates from Appearance -> Editor -> Templates. These templates are lost when I switched to a child theme. Is it possible to copy those post/page templates from default 2022 theme to a child theme? If yes how?

Comment: while you could copy paste, I'd consider this noteworthy enough to report an issue with WordPress itself, my expectation was that child themes would inherit their parent themes templates, wether they were in the database or not

Comment: Yes that's what I thought. I copied template files into my child theme but it doesn't show me the template which I create in parent theme.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the wordpress code editor, it means you modified the actual files. You need to connect to your cpanel > file editor ( or via ftp ) > wp-content > themes / wordpress 2022 and find the files. Copy them to your child theme folder.

If you updated the "wordpress 2022" theme, these are likely gone. This is why is important to use "child" themes, so your modifications do not get overwritten on an update.

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work. I've copied all templates and parts files from parent theme to child theme but it doesn't show me my custom template. Also this copy is not required because by child template should pick up parent's template, I'm not sure though. Not sure if templates are saved in file or in database?

Comment: I found out that the way to export is to use Export option on template editor but that gives me error Zip export not supported.

Comment: are you doing this through your host's cpanel or are you doing this through the wordpress dashboard??

Comment: WP dashboard export gives error. File copy via FTP. I think this copy doesn't work in 2022. Stuff are saved in db and not in files.